# Prevent race-condition in RESTful api in certain scenario

Tags: rest, architecture, race-condition, system-design

I'm currently developing an online course system where students can choose any course and enroll to it. The course will be held one-to-one principle so student will choose a certain date for the course and on that date, there will be an online video meeting with the instructor. Only one instructor and one student for each course session.
Typical use-case flow is:

- Student press "Enroll" button and proceeds to the next page.
- On this page, student chooses the course date from the calendar (only from available dates) and proceeds to checkout page.
- On checkout page, student enters his/her card details and certain amount charged from student.

A race condition may occur in this scenario (let's say there are only 2 users and 1 instructor):

- User1 chooses date from the calendar and proceeds to the checkout page.
- Meanwhile User2 also chooses exactly same date and proceeds to checkout page.
- User2 enters card details faster that User1 and reserves that date.
- User1 enters card details and system charges both students and BINGO (there are two students for the same date).

I don't want to check date availability before payment so I think It'll give a bad user experience so the User must go to the previous step again and choose another date. Even this could happen infinitely :)

Any ideas will be welcomed.
Also, I can change the current enrollment flow to protect security.

Answer (score 2):

The reference you want to review is Pat Helland 2007: [Memories, Guesses and Apologies](https://web.archive.org/web/20100722052618/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pathelland/archive/2007/05/15/memories-guesses-and-apologies.aspx)

You've got a distributed system, and remote clients are looking at local copies of your data that may be out of date.  So your protocol needs to recognize that you will be receiving messages about decisions based on stale data, and have explicit handling for the contingency that the desired outcome of the decision is not currently available.

The REST part is "just" providing the correct affordances for your protocol.

One possible change to your protocol that may help is to introduce the idea of a provisional hold; Alice has a provisional hold on the time slot, and therefore when Bob asks the slot is unavailable, but it might become available later if Alice declines to exercise the option.

(This doesn't *eliminate* the race condition, of course, it just moves it around).

A common protocol solution here is overbooking - you accept *both* claims on the time slot, and then clean up the mess later.

Commercial airlines do this sort of thing all the time; they want to maximize their profit per flight, which means selling more tickets than there are seats on the plane.  They can do this, because enough travelers change their plans later that there is an effective surplus.

But sometimes, too many paying customers show up for the same flight, and then the contingency plans come out -- standby passengers are deferred, ticketed customers are offered compensation packages for changing their plans, and so on.

You probably need contingency protocols anyway (what happens if the instructor has to cancel the appointment, for example because of illness); the race condition during booking is just one more contingency protocol to add to the run book.

Having established what the contingency protocol should be, you then have a second question to explore: what parts of that protocol should be automated.  If conflicts are rare, it may make sense to escalate the problem to a human being to solve, rather than doing so in code.  Sometimes the right answer is for the machine to stay out of the way.

Comment: Thanks for the reference and detailed answer. Yes, there are more possible conflicts than booking, I'm trying to resolve them step-by-step. It's a good idea to involve a human to resolve some problems. Also, I think rather than asking exact date from student, I can ask approximate date, for ex.: 1st part of the day on Monday. Anyway, It takes time to make things "ideal" :)

Answer (score 0):

I want to implement double-check mechanism so:

- When User1 proceeds to calendar page it will create a persistent connection with the server (SSE or WebSocket). And available dates will be shown on real-time. So when User1 selects any date and proceeds to checkout an event will be published and that date will be marked as BLOCKED until the payment done.
- When User1 enters his card details and clicks Pay button the system will check again if that date is really reserved by User1.
- If payment is successful this date will be updated from BLOCKED to RESERVED.

BUT taking into account that this is a REST API with React client, all of the endpoints will be visible to anyone. So an attacker could make a simple brute-force to BLOCK all available dates for the course.